# SQL command not changing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm using the SQL command below to update a column called Address, the value contains line feeds and I want to replace them with a semi-colon. In Query Analayzer the preview looks perfect but when I check the data in Enterprise Manager (MS SQL 2000) I still see the squares i.e. the line feeds. Am I not commiting the change? Where am I going wrong? Thanks

[image]

Comment: This post clarifies your current question, but perhaps you might also want to read a beginner book on SQL. No offense intended, I just found that it's much easier to learn the basics by reading a book instead of scrounging bits of knowledge from the web.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use an **UPDATE** statement!

The replace in the **SELECT** just changes the output not the data in the table.

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE Customers SET Address = REPLACE(Address, char(10) + char(13), ' ') .... etc

--Check you like the change
SELECT * FROM Customers
--COMMIT --uncomment this to commit the changes.
```

Comment: When it is okay you uncomment the --COMMIT part and run it again. Apart from that, good answer, just a little clarification. Otherwise we will get a new question here at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

That would be:

```
UPDATE customers SET Address = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Address,CHAR(10)+CHAR(13),' '),CHAR(10),';'),CHAR(13),';')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Customers
   SET Address = REPLACE(.....)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you perform a replace inside a select only the data "selected" is changed. So the replace is done just before showing you the data. The table data is not touched by a select. The data in the column needs to be updated via an update statement like:

```
UPDATE customers SET
    Address = REPLACE(Address,CHAR(10)+CHAR(13), ' ')
```

Comment: If only fields had methods like Replace

Answer (score -1):

the problem is the when first replace is completed in the text char(10) and char(13) are replaced with ' ' and the next replaces nerev do nothing

Comment: Not true, parts where the CHAR(10) and CHAR(13) are used **together** are replaced by with a space, when a CHAR(10) is standing "alone" it will become a ;. Check the results in his result panel.